# Program window doesn't show up

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm starting programming in C++ and want to start making applications with graphics and user interface.

I've watched many tutorials on the subject,
and have finished the first part of the tutorial
but  the window refused to pop up, and I know that it's working because there are no errors,
and I can see it running in task manager.
Please help.

Hear is the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

bool running = true;

LRESULT CALLBACK windows_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 0;
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        running = false;
    }break;
    default: {
        result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    
    }
    return result;
}

int  WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    //compile window
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = 0;
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = windows_callback;
    //register clases
    RegisterClass(&window_class);
    // create window
    HWND window = CreateWindowA(0, "game stuff", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 720, 360, 0, 0, hInstance, 0); {
        while (running) {
            // input

            // simulate
            MSG mesage;
            while (PeekMessage(&mesage, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
                TranslateMessage(&mesage);
                DispatchMessage(&mesage);
            }

            // render
        }    
    };    
}
```

Comment: #include <Windows.h>                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                 is meant to be part of the code

Comment: [You have to `ShowWindow()` after creating it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window#code-try-3)

Comment: thanks. strange it wasn't in the tutorial

Comment: You start GUI programming in the hard way, i suggest a simpler and more efficient (in general) way: Use a GUI framework like `Qt`.

Comment: no thanks. i have been programing for years but i'm just knew to c++ and hate using game engines

Comment: I wouldn't call Qt a game engine... (anything but not that).

Comment: could someone use the code compile it  and try to fix it .

Comment: there are lots of GUI frameworks on Windows. Almost no one uses raw APIs like that nowadays

Comment: i know but i like doing things myself.

Comment: @user14699592, if you want to learn and do things yourself, maybe you can look into `Qt` and try to recreate a subset of is using `Win32`. You'll learn a lot more that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> window refused to pop up, and I know that it's working because there
> are no errors, and I can see it running in task manager.

You don't check the error for [RegisterClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassa#return-value) and [CreateWindowA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa#returns) functions calls.

Check the return value of `RegisterClass()` you will find that the return value is zero, that indicates failure. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

`CreateWindowA()` also fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

If you use **ANSI** version of these functions, change `WNDCLASS` to `WNDCLASSA`, `RegisterClass` to `RegisterClassA`.

You missed class name in both two functions. The following is an example based on your presented code to make the window show up. You can have a try.

```
CHAR clsName[] = "test";
WNDCLASSA window_class = {};
window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
window_class.lpszClassName = clsName;
window_class.lpfnWndProc = windows_callback;
//register clases
ATOM atom = RegisterClassA(&window_class);
if (0 == atom)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    return 0;
}

// create window
HWND window = CreateWindowA(clsName, "game stuff", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 720, 360, 0, 0, hInstance, 0); 
if (NULL == window)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
```

More references: "[Your First Windows Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program)", "[Unicode in the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api)".

Update:

> why does it have a Chinese name (window's name displays unexecpted)

For using above sample code to display window's name expected you can change project setting to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" like this:

[image]

Or you can use UNICODE APIs (`RegisterClassW` and `CreateWindowW`) with project setting "Use Unicode Character Set".

Or you can use the macros like `RegisterClassEx` and `CreateWindowEx`, it will choose UNICODE or ASCII version API along with your project setting automatically.

Comment: I'm getting an error it says : 
Error C2561 'WinMain': function must return a value 31

Comment: @user14699592 My mistake, have updated my answer you can check.

Comment: thank you soo much but why does it have a Chinese name  ?

Comment: @user14699592 You can also return error code to indiate the error happened.

Comment: @user14699592 Change to UNICODE API can solve this issue. `WCHAR clsName[] = L"test";`... `RegisterClassW(&window_class);`... `CreateWindowW(clsName, L"game stuff"`

Comment: is it meant to be in  different language?

Comment: @user14699592 This caused by a mismatch between character sets. Because your project setting choose UNICODE while your application use ASCII.

Comment: Hello @user14699592, if the answer helps you solve the issue you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Your confirmtion will help other people are searching on similar issue.